# Deploying vb.net application

Tags: vb.net-2010, setup-deployment

I have a vb.net application that deals with Ms Access 2003, Ms Access 2010, Rdlc Report, Crystal Report 13.
How can i deploy my application to be working on all computers even if they have (32bit or 64bit of windows) and even they have (32bit or 64bit of MS Office)?
And how to merge Rdlc and Crystal Report runtime files with it?
With note that Crystal Report also has 32bit and 64bit runtime files.